# Unable to create temporary table in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a query for a process I have to do frequently. I want to take 2 tables imported from excel, join them, and receive output code (without having to use the query design tool).

I have table a, table b, and I want to create table c

here is my code:

```
Insert Into TableC (name,
id,
gender,
dob,
issues,
other,
program_name)
SELECT 
a.name,
a.id,
a.gender,
a.dob,
b.issues,
b.other,
a.program_name
from 
(TableA a 
left join TableB b on b.id = a.id);
```

I keep getting various errors, one being file not found, one being unknown field in insert into. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to use that query to *create* [TableC], or to *populate* an existing table?

Comment: Your SQL requires that table 'C' already exists - since you are 'inserting into'. Your SQL looks ok for an 'append query', but your question states you want to 'create table c'.  That will require something like: SELECT TableA.ID, TableA.FldA, TableA.FldB, TableB.FldA, TableB.FldB INTO TableC
FROM TableA LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID;

Comment: I got it to work, I needed to make the column headers on the existing table germane to the query. sorry for the bad explanation.